# Frustrating CSS float issue

Tags: css, wordpress, mailchimp

I've had two developers look at this and they haven't been able to figure out what is causing the issue.

On the following site, the subscribe bar (top of page) looks fine and functions properly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but in IE an issue occurs where it shifts the Subscribe button down a line and overlaps with the 'Resources' nav item. A specific width must be set for the float to work properly but when you set the width to auto it floats under the element to the left of it. While it still functions properly this way, it is problematic because it looks awful.

I believe the issue is CSS related but please also note I am using a theme in WordPress and integrating a MailChimp subscribe form.

Any thoughts of suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance - Ashleigh

[Site Reference](http://deniselalonde.com)

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the #mc_signup DIV to a higher value? When I set it to 530px the form is show on one line only.

Comment: Hi Denise, Just so you're aware - it's doing the same display-thing in Opera, too (don't ignore Opera.) So what end result do you want? Where should the Subscribe button be?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too localized, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I'm not a CSS pro either.

I'm looking at your website using Firefox 16.0.2 and I see the same problem you are describing.

Using Firebug, I believe you should remove the `width: 430px` from `<div id="mc_signup">`. The current width is too small for the complete form and I think that is the reason for the subscribe button to move below the rest of the form. (it simply wraps because there is not enough horizontal space)

See the screenshot, the blue area is the `<div id="mc_signup">`, which is limited to 430px.

[screenshot http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/1540/denised.png](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/1540/denised.png)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: As a side note, I recommend downloading the Firebug add-on for Firefox, it really gives you insight in the CSS of your page and let's you play with the CSS rules inside your browser.

Comment: This answer is in the right direction, but because that particular declaration is buried deep in a WordPress Theme, I think the recommendation should be to override it in custom CSS with `#mc_signup { width: auto!important; }`

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing issues under Chrome. Increasing `#mc_signup`'s width to `440px;` should fix your problem.

Alternatively you could change `#subscribe .wrapper .center` to `width: 100%; text-align: center;` and replace the floats on `.leftcopy` and `#mc_signup` with `display: inline-block;`

I recommend you edit your question if you want a more specific answer. Please add screenshots.

I strongly recommend you look at the following link on how to properly float elements. 
[www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem, you described is consist in Opera and Chrome as well.
But I removed the `padding: 0px 10px;` part from `input#mc_signup_submit.button` and it was fine.